# Making an immutable class: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to make an immutable class. Without further ado:

```
#import "MatrixRow2.h"

@implementation MatrixRow2

@synthesize rows;

-(MatrixRow2*) initWithFractionNumberArray:(NSArray*)array
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        rows = array;
    }

    return self;
}

-(MatrixRow2*) rowByMultiplyingByFractionNumber:(FractionNumber*)number
{
    NSArray *temp = rows.copy;
    MatrixRow2 *newRow = [[MatrixRow2 alloc] initWithFractionNumberArray:temp];

    for (int i=0; i < newRow.rows.count; i++) {
        [[newRow.rows objectAtIndex:i] multiplyByFraction:number];
    }

    return newRow;
}

-(NSString*) description
{
    return [rows description];
}

@end
```

And the tester code:

```
MatrixRow2 *r = [[MatrixRow2 alloc] initWithFractionNumberArray:tempRow];

NSLog(@"Initial row values: %@", r);

FractionNumber *randomMultiplier = [FractionNumber fractionFromRandomFractionWithMaxNumerator:100 maxDenominator:99 integerChanceIn10:8];

MatrixRow2 *r2= [r rowByMultiplyingByFractionNumber:randomMultiplier];

NSLog(@"%@ * %@ = %@", r, randomMultiplier, r2);
```

And the output is:

```
2012-04-20 22:33:29.081 RREF[3586:f803] Initial row values: (
    70,
    94,
    98,
    90
)
2012-04-20 22:33:29.083 RREF[3586:f803] (
    770,
    1034,
    1078,
    990
) * 11 = (
    770,
    1034,
    1078,
    990
)
```

In the second output line, the value of r has changed to the multiplied value. It should read:

```
[70 94 98, 90] * 11 = [770 1034 1078 990]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing a shallow copy of the array. You need to copy each item in the array before you mutate it.

This will involve creating a copy of each item and adding it to a new array (or updating the items in the copied array with copies of each item).

Everything that an immutable object works with either needs to be immutable or copied before mutating.

Comment: Well, I would say that he (and you, somewhat) are conceiving of immutability the wrong way.  An `NSArray` is immutable without making a copy of the elements.  The array is immutable even if the elements are neither private nor immutable.  Frankly, I think the problem is that his `FractionNumber` class is mutable.  That's quite odd.  It should be immutable, just like `NSNumber`.

Comment: I agree, but it all comes down to your intentions and how you use it. If you build something like this as a way of being safer in multithreading, then it just matters that you've kept with the intention of the class's immutability. In this case, it's the responsibility of the programmer to keep with the intensions. Building the whole class out of immutable objects would be a much better idea, though.

Comment: Ken, the FractionNumber class is a class I made myself. It was not immutable either. I've fixed the problem now, thanks everyone!